# Efficient way of handling form elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am currently refactoring my code, and have this curiosity on my mind. I'm not PRO to javascript, so anyone's comment is acceptable and highly appreciated. :) Now my question is this, is it good to store all my elements to an object and eventually use its values to be manipulated anywhere in the code? Please look my block of code:

```
var regForm = {
    form: {},
    construct: function () {
        this.loadElements();

        return this;
    },
    loadElements: function () {
        this.form['form'] = document.getElementById('myForm');
        // get all the active fields of the form
        var formKeys = getFormFields(this.form['form']);
        for (var val in formKeys) {
            var field = formKeys[val];
            this.form[field] = document.getElementById(field);
        }
        this.form['submit_btn'] = document.getElementById('submit_btn');
    },
    getFormData: function () {
        var form = this.form['form']; // is this good?
        .....
    }
}

function getFormFields(form) {
    var obj = [];
    var elements = form.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea, checkbox, radio");

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        var el = elements[i];
        if (el.name)
            obj.push(el.name);
    }

    return obj;
}
```

I have read some articles about optimizing and found one topic about reducing DOM access, it is stated that it is too slow to access a DOM element every time so **its better to store it on a local variable**. But I am in doubt if what I've done on my code is the same as storing it on a local variable? Any thoughts, comments, suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: the `var form =` is a local variable. However, if your `var regForm =` is accessible globally, then by proxy, `regForm.form['form']` is also globally accessible

Comment: A property of an object is just as good as a local variable. It's totally fine to store the DOM elements there.

Comment: Can you show us that `getFormFields` function? Its usage looks overly complicated. (For starters, it could just return the elements themselves instead of their ids)

Comment: Hi @Bergi, I have already appended the code for `getFormFields`. Thanks :) Can you please explain why it looks overly complicated?

Comment: @Chisskarzz a) because you are returning names, not elements b) because you require every element to have the same `name` and `id` c) because you could just use [`form.elements[name]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Bergi. I really don't know that `form.element` do exists. Great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a DOM property that does most of this work for you: [`HTMLFormElement#elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements). It keeps track of every form control inside a form, and allows you to access them easily by both their index (useful for looping over all controls) and `id` (useful for accessing a particular control).

### Demo:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('example-form')

var elements = form.elements

// Access form controls by index:
console.log(elements[0].value)
console.log(elements[1].value)

// ...or by `id`:
console.log(elements['text-field'].value)
console.log(elements['numeric-field'].value)
```

```html
<form id="example-form">
  <input id="text-field" type="text" value="I am an example text input field">
  <input id="numeric-field" type="number" value="9001">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @gyre! I'm gonna try this out and will get back to you. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! Let me know if you have any questions.